# Angular: Cannot import packages with @angular-devkit/build-angular:application

Tags: angular, leaflet, angular-devkit

I'm using Angular 17 and have [Leaflet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet) and [leaflet.gridlayer.googlemutnt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet.gridlayer.googlemutant) package installed. The `leaflet` package works fine but when I'm importing `leaflet.gridlayer.googlemutant` I had this error:
`[vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve entry for package "leaflet.gridlayer.googlemutant". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json.`

It's only works when I configured the `angular.json` to

```
"build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/fe-avema",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
...
```

But I want to use the application builder like this for high performance:

```
"build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/fe-avema",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
...
```